Layered maps with efficient updates
Consider the operation of "layering" a maps on top of another. For example given the following maps:
m_1 = { "foo": 1, "bar": 2 }
m_2 = { "foo": 3, "baz": 4 }

then layering m2 on top of m1 would result in the map layered(m_2, m_1) = { "foo": 3, "bar": 2, "baz": 4 }, i.e. the map consisting of the elements of m_2 and all the elements in m1 whose key is not present in m2.
Given this operation, I would like to apply it to a sequence of maps, obtaining all the intermediate layered maps. That is, given the list of maps [m_1, m_2, m_3, ...] I would like to obtain the list [l_1, l_2, l_3, ...] where:

l_1 = m_1
l_i = layered(m_i, l_{i-1})

I would also like to update any of the maps m_i and efficiently obtain the updated list of layered maps l_i.
Is there some kind of data structure that would allow me to do this? In particular I'm interested to know if there exist something more efficient than implementing lookups on l_i as performing lookups on m_i, then m_{i-1}, m_{i-2}, and so on until either one succeeds or m_1 is reached.
It would also be interesting if this worked for trees of maps as well, rather than just lists, i.e. transform a tree of maps to a tree with the same shape where each node holds the result of layering all the maps on the path from the original tree root to the corresponding node.
Edit: to give a slightly better explanation of what I mean in the last part on trees, consider a tree where each node i is associated to a map m_i. The goal would be to associate each node to another map l_i where l_root = m_root and l_child = layered(m_child, l_parent)

Please don't append "Edit: more information".  Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.  If you have multiple questions, they should normally be asked separately in separate posts.

For each key (e.g., "foo"), maintain a sorted list of all indices of the maps that contain this key.  (The "index" of the map $m_i$ is $i$.)  For instance, in your example, the key "foo" is associated with the list [1, 3], "bar" is associated with [2], and "baz" with [4].
Store the sorted list as a balanced binary search tree, so that all operations on it can be done in $O(\log n)$ time.
To compute $l_i$, for each key $k$, you search the sorted list for $k$ to find the largest index that is $\le i$, then look  up $k$ in the corresponding map.  You can find the index in $O(\log n)$ time, so the running time is $O(n \log n)$.
To update a map $m_i$: if you are inserting a key $k$ into $m_i$, then insert $i$ into the sorted list for $k$; if you are deleting the key $k$, then delete $i$ from the sorted list for $k$.  These can be done in $O(\log n)$ time.
This is essentially optimal, apart from a $O(\log n)$ factor slowdown.

That answers the main question, but I'm not sure what you mean in the last part on the trees. Maybe I was a bit unclear on that part, so I edited my question to include a better explanation.
